# Repository structure for flux/kustomize for common software on multiple clusters

Tags: amazon-web-services, kustomize

I have a repository which manages multiple k8s clusters, the structure is as follows:

```
clusters/cluster-1/flux
clusters/cluster-2/flux
flux/common/common-software-1
flux/common/common-software-1
...
```

Each cluster's `flux` directory contains overrides for various configuration values e.g.:

1. Cluster name
2. AWS role ARNs

Creating a new cluster configuration is complex and error-prone because I need to duplicate the flux directory, which contains multiple files/`Kustomization` resources, and then modify all of the overrides with the cluster specific information.

I would like to simplify this by having a configuration/properties file for each cluster which contains the cluster specific values, and then have more generic Kustiomize resources. e.g.

`clusters/cluster-1/cluster-1.properties` file containing:

```
cluster-name=cluster-1
software-role-arn=aws:...:00000000:role/software-role-name
...
```

Then I could use Kustomize [replacements](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/replacements/) to replace values in a common set of files. However, I've bumped into a few issues:

1. It seems like I need to copy-paste a big block of replacement configuration into each cluster's config files.
2. It seems like it's not possible to reference a properties file from a directory outside of the referencing resource's file path.

Is there a solution which would let me do this? Or a completely different way to reduce the amount of duplication?